# Why does Unity editor freeze up if left unfocused for a while?

Tags: unity

If Unity editor loses focus for too long (such as because I'm tabbed out into my browser or Blender), then I find that it needs about 15-30 seconds until I can interact with it again when it gets focus again. It seems like it is paused.

Is this a bug or my fault?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is related to a model which I am editing in blender and use in unity, each time if I save the model, then unity is stucked, because unity has to import the new model. There is not always a loading bar or other indicator that an import is going on, so this was confusing and unclear.